# Print Concatenation of Zig-Zag String in ‘n’ Rows

Tags: c++, string, vector

> I have been given a string and number of rows `n`. Print the string formed by concatenating `n` rows when input string is written in row-wise Zig-Zag fashion

```
std::string str = convert("PAYPALISHIRING", 3); //str == "PAHNAPLSIIGYIR"
```

Here is a visual image

```
P.......A........H.......N
..A..P....L....S....I...I....G
....Y.........I........R
```

I wrote the following code

```
string Solution::convert(string A, int B) {//B is no of rows in zigzag pattern
    if(B==1)
        return A;
    int n=B;
    vector<string> vec;
    int dir=0;//0 means down, 1 means up
    int row=0;
    for(int i=0;i<A.length();i++)
    {
        vec[row].append(A,i,1);
        if(row==n-1)
            dir=1;//change to upwards
        if(row==0)
            dir=0;//change to downwards

        if(dir==0) row++;
        else row--;
    }
    string ans="";
    for(int i=0;i<B;i++)
        ans.append(vec[i]);

    return ans;
}
```

But for all `B >= 2` it gives a segmentation fault.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `vec[row].append(A,i,1);`.

You are accessing the string at index `row`, but `vec` is empty! You can't do that, so you get a segmentation fault!

You need to specify the size of the vector:

```
//'vec' will never have more than 'B' elements
std::vector<std::string> vec(B);
```

Comment: Yeah...Thanks a lot...It helped!!